# return an array instead of a tuple from a NumPy function

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have the following code:

```
return atleast_1d(0.4*P2), atleast_1d(k_uni)
```

My function returns a tuple. What is the quickest way to make this return as an array?

Comment: Maybe `return array((atleast_1d(0.4*P2), atleast_1d(k_uni)))`? Btw. your question title says nothing about the contents of your question.

Comment: Hi! Please take some time to review your question and brush it up a little. People will be more willing to help if it looks like you actually took some effort on writting a proper question :)
You should probably start by adding your actual question to the title.

Comment: OK. I will correct myself in the next time.

Comment: If it's a bit more specific it helps people to work out which questions to look at based on their personal expertise, and that helps you to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This return statement creates a tuple, consisting of 2 arrays.

```
return atleast_1d(0.4*P2), atleast_1d(k_uni)
```

You'd get a tuple if you did

```
return 1, 2
return [1,2,3],{'one':1}
etc
```

I'd suggest calling the function with

```
x, y = foo(...)
```

Now the 2 arrays defined in the return statement are assigned to 2 variables.  You can combine them in what ever way that works (depends on their shape).

```
np.array((x,y))
np.concatenate((x,y))
etc
```

Note that I am actually giving those functions a tuple.  I could have written it as a list.

The issue isn't how the function returns a tuple, but how you want to combine 2 arrays into one.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I just want that one line of coding in the return statement should return an array (hdstack of two arrays) instead of a tuple.

Comment: What's wrong with `return np.hstack((array1, array2))`?  It's your choice whether you apply `hstack` before or after the return.

Comment: Actually your logic works here. Thank you :) . It is solved now.